# react-select doesn't keep indexes on manipulated arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing, react-select

In an array of react-selects, any input before the last one will break indexing for the following ones. I know about uuid for key (which is not recommended) and also about Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) for key. But I still can't get this to work.

The key generated with Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) breaks the input: you can't populate anything into the field.

It's an indexing problem and I believe it's a problem from within the plugin. I need to clarify this isn't the issue hopefully.

I've created a codesandbox with Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) as key so you'd see.

https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-dcvdj?file=/example.tsx

Add on at least one input and try to populate. It won't let you.

Put `index` in `key` and you'll see you can populate, but when you try to delete it, the value stays the same and instead the one under that one gets deleted (indexing issue, I know). This is because when state is updated, map will run again and will reindex the list once again.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to reference you AsyncSelect values into an array like so:

```
state = {
    inputValue: "",
    fieldsArr: [],
    values: []
  };
```

Consequently your `render()` function would look like:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>inputValue: "{this.state.inputValue}"</pre>
        {this.state.fieldsArr.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <span>{item}</span>
            <AsyncSelect
              cacheOptions
              loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
              defaultOptions
              value={this.state.values[index]} // <--- This will reference your state value
              onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, index)}
              onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
            <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}>delete</button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Then you will add an `handleChange` callback to handle the AsyncSelect `onChange` event.

```
handleChange(el, index) {
    let vals = this.state.values;
    vals[index] = el;
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, values: vals }));
  }
```

And finally edit the `handleDelete` and `handleAdd` functions accordigly:

```
handleAdd = () => {
    let newArr = this.state.fieldsArr;
    let values = this.state.values;
    newArr.push(this.state.fieldsArr.length + 1);
    values.push("");
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, fieldsArr: newArr }));
  };

  handleDelete = (index) => {
    let newArr = this.state.fieldsArr;
    let values = this.state.values;
    newArr.splice(index, 1);
    values.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, fieldsArr: newArr, values }));
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the link to your fork to verify please? I figured it out but I might get something from your work

Comment: Absolutely https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-8h677

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-8h677?file=/example.tsx

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a counter, add to that counter on add field, then on delete using indexOf item to delete.

https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-dcvdj?file=/example.tsx